# Latency for Dataset in Oozie Coordinator

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, oozie

Looking to have a job that runs based on the availability of data sets made in Hive partitions. I have gotten this to work, but now I want it to run such that all my feeds run at the nominal time, but one will always run at a day delayed. So if today is 5-19, all the feeds need to be there for 5-19 except one, which we will want for 5-18.

This is what I currently have:

```
    <dataset name="mvHost" frequency="${coord:days(1)}" initial-instance="${jobStart}" timezone="America/New_York">
        <uri-template>${nameNode}/apps/hive/warehouse/uat_db.db/mv_host/create_date=${YEAR}${MONTH}${DAY}</uri-template>
        <done-flag></done-flag>
    </dataset>
    <!-- ensure MV_INTERFACE exists on partition date, need to delay by ONE day -->
    <dataset name="mvInterface" frequency="${coord:days(1)}" initial-instance="${jobStart}" timezone="America/New_York">
        <uri-template>${nameNode}/apps/hive/warehouse/uat_db.db/mv_interface/create_date=${YEAR}${MONTH}${DAY}</uri-template>
        <done-flag></done-flag>
    </dataset>

</datasets>
<input-events>
    <data-in name="input1" dataset="mvHost">
        <instance>${coord:current(0)}</instance>
    </data-in>
    <data-in name="input2" dataset="mvInterface">
        <instance>${coord:current(0)}</instance>
    </data-in>
</input-events>
```

What is the best way to instill the latency? I have tried editing the instance to be ${coord:current(-24)} but that failed. Also, I have tried using coord:dateOffset on initial-instance for MV_INTERFACE but the coordinator would never build.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need [${coord:offset(n, String timeUnit)}](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.0/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a6.6.2._coord:offsetint_n_String_timeUnit_EL_Function_for_Synchronous_Datasets) here.
It's used anywhere you use ${coord:current(n)} but allows you to specify time offset (both positive and negative) at dataset materialization time.
So, for your example:

```
   <datasets>
    <dataset name="mvHost" frequency="${coord:days(1)}" initial-instance="${jobStart}" timezone="America/New_York">
        <uri-template>${nameNode}/apps/hive/warehouse/uat_db.db/mv_host/create_date=${YEAR}${MONTH}${DAY}</uri-template>
        <done-flag></done-flag>
    </dataset>
    <!-- ensure MV_INTERFACE exists on partition date, need to delay by ONE day -->
    <dataset name="mvInterface" frequency="${coord:days(1)}" initial-instance="${jobStart}" timezone="America/New_York">
        <uri-template>${nameNode}/apps/hive/warehouse/uat_db.db/mv_interface/create_date=${YEAR}${MONTH}${DAY}</uri-template>
        <done-flag></done-flag>
    </dataset>
</datasets>

<input-events>
    <data-in name="input1" dataset="mvHost">
        <instance>${coord:current(0)}</instance>
    </data-in>
    <data-in name="input2" dataset="mvInterface">
        <instance>${coord:offset(-1, "DAY")}</instance>
    </data-in>
</input-events>
```

If 2016-01-01T00:00 is coordinator materialization time, then
dataset "mvHost" materialization time will be (the same) 2016-01-01T00:00,
dataset "mvInterface" will be 2015-12-31T00:00.